# Fluent Nhibernate - Unrecognised method call: System.Linq.Enumerbale:Boolean Any

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to make a query but I'm getting an exception -

> Unrecognised method call: System.Linq.Enumerbale:Boolean Any

Now, I get why i get the exception, because I'm trying to use linq inside queryover, but I can't figure out how to do it without it:

```
Disjunction dis = new Disjunction();

if (KasafotIds.Any())
{
    dis.Add(Restrictions.Where<Entity>(x => x.Kasafot.Any(m => KasafotIds.Contains(m.Id))));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `dis.Add(Restrictions.Where<State>(x => x.IsActive).IsIn(KasafotIds));`

Answer (score 0):

you need to join explicitly when using QueryOver. This might work:

```
var dis = new Disjunction();

if (KasafotIds.Any())
{
    Foo alias = null;
    query.JoinAlias<Foo>(x => x.Kasafot, () => alias);
    dis.Add(Restrictions.Where(() => alias.Id.IsIn(KasafotIds)));
}
```